# vfork - suspends the calling process or the calling thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, vfork

The man page for vfork sayas :  "vfork - create a child process and block parent"
down below in the description "vfork() differs from fork(2) in that the calling thread is suspended"

In most documentation it says "suspend the process"

So, which is true ?
Does the answer depend on Linux version ?

Thank
zmau

Comment: What matters is the documentation _for your platform_. In Linux, per the man page, the calling thread is suspended. In other platforms, this may be different. If you expect portable behaviour in this matter, you cannot have it.

Comment: I do not understand the answer. Is it possible that the answer for this question is dfifferent on arm than on X86 ?